# Apple Swift Tutorial: Rating buttons layout

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

I'm currently following this Apple's iOS Swift tutorial for beginner which explain how to create the rating star view and I don't understand something about the layout code. To layout the rating buttons they created from code using a for-in loop, they create another method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)

    // Offset each button's origin by the length of the button plus spacing.
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (44 + 5))
        button.frame = buttonFrame
    }
}
```

But in at the initialisation of buttons :

```
for _ in 0..<5 {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        // Add event listener
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.rateButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        ratingButtons += [button]

        addSubview(button)
    }
```

Can't they simply adapt the code and, instead of using a wildcard ( _ ) in the for-in loop, use an index and do something like this ? :

```
for i in 0..<5 {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (i * 49), y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        // Add event listener
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.rateButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        ratingButtons += [button]

        addSubview(button)
    }
```

I am learning Swift and I don't understand why they override the layoutSubviews method instead of doing that at initialisation. Tell me which way is the cleaner please. Here is the tutorial link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the frame for the containing rect is not known before the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is called. The `layoutSubviews` method is called after this method, and each time `layoutIfNeeded` is called for the view.

This means that the layout can be adapted to updates in the view and only called from one method.

Whether one method is cleaner than another is subjective, and really up to each individual to determine, but at least you should write your UI code in a way that follows the lifecycle of the view.